# Magento 2: how to get shipment id by product id?

Tags: magento2, product, shipment

For a single order, I want to get shipment id by product id if shipment created in that order.

Answer (score 0):

You will get shipping id from product id by getting `sales_shipment_item` collection and filter product id.
Hope it helps..!!